# how to place link to URL / Webpage on the launcher?

Tags: gnome, launcher, symbolic-link, url

Has anyone pinned a URL to the Launcher (Ubuntu 20.04)? Nothing I've tried works.

*Please show how you have done this with a working example.* (a link to AskUbuntu.com?)

There are a great many posts on creating desktop links, but none that get them onto my launch bar.

Thanks a million.

richolland

Comment: There is a tag Unity. Do you use the Unity desktop? That is not default on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There is no "easy" way (i.e. drag and drop) but the way indicated in the linked post will work in the Unity desktop and the default Gnome Shell desktop alike.